# Laravel\Passport\Client returns null instance

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

My Auth API was working but now it gives error. I can register successfully but I cant get the return of the login token because I get an error:

`TypeError: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\UserController::getTokenAndRefreshToken() must be an instance of Laravel\Passport\Client, null given, called in /var/www/laravel/app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php on line 44 in file /var/www/laravel/app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php on line 47`

Like I said, it was working before, I just added another model and created one-to-many relationship with user model but I don't think that has got anything to do with Passport. 
Why I get a null object from OClient::where('password_client', 1)->first();

I create user like this in UserController's register method.

```
$user = User::create($input); 
$oClient = OClient::where('password_client', 1)->first();
return $this->getTokenAndRefreshToken($oClient, $user->email, $password);
```

```
    public function getTokenAndRefreshToken(OClient $oClient, $email, $password) { 
        $oClient = OClient::where('password_client', 1)->first();
        $http = new Client;
        $response = $http->request('POST', '/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => $oClient->id,
                'client_secret' => $oClient->secret,
                'username' => $email,
                'password' => $password,
                'scope' => '*',
            ],
        ]);

        $result = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
        return response()->json($result, $this->successStatus);
    }
```

Comment: if you did a `migrate:refresh` or cleared some tables, try `php artisan passport:install`

Comment: This solved the problem, thank you!